# Always On Availability Groups on Windows 2012 Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I am trying to enable the Always On Availability Groups feature of SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition on Windows Server Standard Edition 2012, but it says the feature requires X64 Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2012 or Windows 2008 Enterprise edition or above.

I already have Windows Standard 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, why can't I enable this feature?

Comment: Can you provide the results from `SELECT @@VERSION` and have you already put the Windows machines in a WSFC?

Comment: I have already installed WFCS with two nodes, fileshare as witness and installed sql enterprise edition on to it. Following is the version info Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (Intel X86) 
 Dec 28 2012 19:06:41 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1):

Per the information you provided from `SELECT @@VERSION` you are running the x86 version of SQL Server 2012. It would appear that the OS and SQL Server architecture must match in order for Availability Groups to function.

This means that you would either need to change your SQL Server installation to the x64, or go to a prior version of Windows (2008) and install the x86 version of that.

My recommendation would be to adjust your existing install and make it x64. This provides many enhancements such as not needing to mess with things like PAE and AWE when using more than 4GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

AlwaysOn Availability Groups require Windows cluster services. With 2008r2 and before, those are only available in the enterprise and datacenter editions of the Windows operating system. Check these for more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771404(v=ws.11).aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability The second article talks more to SQL 2016, though I've used it as an aide when working with SQL 2014. In addition, Brent Ozar's site is a valuable resource. Check this out as well: https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups/

Comment: This is innacurate. Windows enterprise is NOT required, except when running 2008 or earlier. Windows Server Failover Clustering is supported in Standard Edition and higher from the 2012 release. A worksheet for feature supportability for R2 can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41703

Comment: @Nic thank you for catching that - I've only ever used the enterprise edition of Windows. Answer updated.